# Microstrategy Library server using wrong hostname

Tags: tomcat, microstrategy

An error has occurred with the Intelligence Server.

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://servername279.asd:34962/api/bulkreadobjects

Unable to determine IP address from host name servername279.asd

This is the error I get from browser, the mstr site can be accessed via internet , projects and everything working, just Library doesnt. It shoud use the websites URL instead of servername279.asd.

Where can I set this ? I grepped everywhere on the server (its running on Linux), no luck.

Comment: 34962 should be the iserver rest port, do you expose it from the server?

Comment: By default, the library should be exposed in 80 or 8080.